# Iterating through a list and comparing places - Python

Tags: python, list

So, I am trying something simple. I am trying to go through a list, which, once sorted, I can see if the next number along is higher than the previous.
If this is so, I can add it into a new list:

```
def longestRun(L):
'''
assume L is not empty
'''

new_list=[]
list_place=0


# we then need to iterate along the sorted List L

print L[list_place]
print L[list_place+1]
if L[list_place] < L[list_place+1]
    new_list+=L[list_place]
    list_place+=1
```

Comment: Your problem is....?

Comment: By sorting the list you have guaranteed that `L[idx] < L[idx+1]`

Comment: To be pedantic, it's `<=`

Comment: There is no iteration (looping) in that code.

Comment: Apologies, I need to edit the code. The list should not be sorted!

Answer (score 0):

```
L = [1, 2, 3]
list_place = 0
new_list = []

while list_place < len(L)-1:
    print L[list_place]
    if L[list_place] < L[list_place+1]:
        new_list.append(L[list_place])
    list_place+=1

print len(new_list)
```

To iterate, first you need a loop statement, like `while`. Second, if you don't increment `list_place` every time you iterate, once if statement evaluates to false, it goes into loop forever.

Comment: I have tried the above code, but for some reason the if statement gives me a syntax error?!

Comment: Check indentation please.

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot `:` after `if`